# Azure GET action with one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, azure-sql-database, asp.net-web-api

I have to tables with one-to-many relationship in Azure SQL database.

```
--Countries
create table Countries
(
    ID int not null primary key clustered identity,
    Name varchar(100) not null
)
--Cities
create table Cities
(
    ID int not null primary key clustered identity,
    Name varchar(100) not null,
    CountryID int not null foreign key references Countries(ID) on delete cascade
)
```

I've created Web API using Entity Framework Database first model. Generated classes looks as following:

Country.cs

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Country()
    {
        this.Cities = new HashSet<City>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
```

City.cs

```
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public City()
    {

    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }    
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
```

CitiesController.cs

```
    private TripperDBEntities db = new TripperDBEntities();

    // GET: api/Cities
    public IQueryable<City> GetCities()
    {
        return db.Cities;
        }

// POST: api/Countries
        [ResponseType(typeof(Country))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCountry(Country country)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Countries.Add(country);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = country.ID }, country);
        }
```

Calling GET Countries or GET Cities returns

> 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: An HTTP response code of 500 (generally) means an exception occurred while processing the request. You'll need to examine your server-side logs and figure out what the exception is. From there it will probably be clear what the problem is.

Comment: It'd also be handy to see the code for the get action.

Comment: I added get and put action in my question. I think my code would need update to trace server-side logs.

Comment: Still slightly confused - when you say "When I add First city to the database, GET action returns 500 error", how is the first city getting added, and are you actually having a problem with the GET or PUT action?

Comment: I'm sorry, there should be POST action. I don't have any problems with adding and getting countries. Also if I don't have any city, api responses right. After adding first city, I am not able to get Cities or Countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the related data, it creates a circular object graph. 
For more information how to handle it, check following: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-4